# Pandas Assign Same Value to All Unique Values in Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

H, I have a dataset with two columns, one of them is `target`. If I group all the unique values in target, I get an array of `826` elements. My problem is when trying to assign some values based on this uniqueness.

I have a second array, called `array` with contains a total of `826` values (of string type) to assign to each row in my dataset based on their values in the column `target`, here is an example.

```
print(len(df['target'].unique()))
# 826

print(len(array))
# 826

print(array[0])
# "Some string value"
```

When I try to iterate over both target and array, and assign each value of the array to the rows in the dataset with that target, I get that the new created column, called `final_target`, has only `822` unique values!

```
for target, new_value in zip(df['target'].unique(), array):
    df.loc[df["target"] == target, 'final_target'] = new_value
```

IN theorty the code seems to be fine, but when checking the unique values in the column `final_target`, I get:

```
len(df['final_target'].unique())
# 822
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this, I have to note that both columns (`target` and `final_target`) have the same total length (100,000 samples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do

```
#df['final_target'] = df['target'].astype('category').cat.codes

df['final_target'] = df['target'].replace(dict(zip(df['target'].astype('category').cat.codes, array)))
```

Comment: I think OP has a secondary array for assigning - *I have a second array, called array*

Comment: That's true, how I could assign the values of the array?